# Is there something in c# similar to java's @override annotation?

Tags: c#, java, overriding

I've used the [@Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) in java and has come in quite handy. Is there anything similar in c#?

Comment: I dunno, the `override` keyword?

Comment: Ok, sorry, that was a really stupid question. I was looking for an annotation but couldn't find one. Forgot it was part of the method signature. Still a bit new to c#.

Comment: C# actually had the `override` keyword first. It proved useful enough that they added the feature as an annotation to Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C# compiler provides compile-time checking for method overrides, including checking if the method is actually overriding as you intended.  You can indicate that a method should be overridden using the .NET `override` keyword.

Comment: There is no .Net compiler.  (You mean C#)

Answer (score 4):

In C#, you must use the `override` keyword to override functions.

If you use `override` without a matching `virtual` or `abstract` base function, you'll get a compiler error.

If you don't use `override`, and there is a matching base function, you'll get a compiler warning (unless you add `new`).

Answer (score 2):

In CSharp, `override` keyword meaning is totally different from the Java world. The equivalent in Csharp World is explicit implementation but it has a [drawback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520727/why-cant-i-call-methods-within-a-class-that-explicitly-implements-an-interface).

```
interface IShape
{
     void Display();
}

class Square : IShape
{
     void IShape.Display()
     {

     }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

No, yes. It makesn o sesne to have an anotation because in C# there is an  override kkeyword in the langauge and the compiler warnds if you "hide" a method. So, either you say "new" or "override" directly as part of the method.

Java basically uses the annotation to hide a mistake in the langauge specifications.

Please read the language specificastions for C#. Completely.

Comment: Why is it a mistake? There is really nothing about overriding that any modern compiler can't work out on its own. I find it mostly useful from a self-documenting perspective, and having to explicitly declare my intent makes me keep track of things. But is it necessary for compilation? Not really.

Comment: C# also does not have it for "the compiler" but to be explicit. Overriding without warning is a possible error condition. Java made the mistake to make everything virtual by default and auto override, and it introduces a ton of possible errors.

Comment: So what? ;) Only sheep have no opinion, and they get slaughered. I personally think if you want a weak typed langauge, go and get one. Otherwise... it is a weak point.