# How come Dictionary<TKey, TValue> has private interface methods?

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, .net-6.0, idictionary

While I was trying to implement the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface on one of my classes, I chose to delegate all the interface methods of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` to an instance of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` that I had instantiated in my class. Then, I was quite confused that the IDE complained that I was trying to access private methods of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. However, these methods are ought to be part of the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface! How can they be private? I checked the source code of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and indeed it has a private implementation of `CopyTo`. How am I supposed to delegate `CopyTo` and how is it even possible for an interface method to be private in the first place?

The IDE says that `CopyTo` is private in the following code.

```
public abstract class BindingCollectionTemplate<TName, TValue>: ScopeTemplate, IDictionary<TName, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TName, TValue> dictionary = new();
    // ...
    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TName, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        dictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex); // Accessing a private interface method??
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. A [mcve] please.

Comment: The implementaton of [`CopyTo(Array, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.system-collections-icollection-copyto?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-system-collections-icollection-copyto(system-array-system-int32)) is not private, it's **explicit**.  See [Explicit Interface Implementation (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

Comment: See [C# Interfaces. Implicit implementation versus Explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/143405).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I call methods within a class that explicitly implements an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520727/why-cant-i-call-methods-within-a-class-that-explicitly-implements-an-interface)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method comes from `ICollection<T>` interface and dictionary implements it:

```cs
public interface IDictionary<TKey,TValue>
 : ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>, ...
```

In dictionary this method is implemented via an [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) which [uses the private `CopyTo`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a3981dde2de089061fe7c857d8bd5da573546a3f/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L1060):

```cs
void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(
    KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, 
    int index) => CopyTo(array, index);
```

So you can access it via interface:

```
class MyDict<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _internal = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex) =>
        ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)_internal).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
}
```